# Obtener listado paises en android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Deseo obtener un listado de paises en Android con Kotlin

Para obter el listado de los paises con su ISO

```kotlin
val isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries()
for (countryCode in isoCountryCodes){
    Log.d(TAG, "iso3: $countryCode")
}

//AD, AE, AF, AG, AI, AL,  AM, AO, AQ, AR...
```

Me falta como obtener el nombre del país a partir de su código `ISO 3166`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el nombre del pais a partir de su `ISO 3166` se debe usar `Locale` con su propiedad `displayCountry` se puede obtener el nombre del país

```kotlin
val isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries()
for (countryCode in isoCountryCodes){
    val locale = Locale(Locale.getDefault().isO3Language, countryCode)
    val countryName = locale.displayCountry
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $countryCode $countryName")
}
```

Su salida es así

```
AD Andorra
AE Emiratos Árabes Unidos
AF Afganistán
AG Antigua y Barbuda
AI Anguila
AL Albania
AM Armenia
AO Angola
AQ Antártida
...
```